# docker on windows ignoring ctrl-c

Tags: windows, docker

If i run

```
docker run alpine sleep 120
```

on a linux docker host, it is possible to to press CTRL-C to stop the container.
The same does not work if i try the same on Docker Desktop for Windows. I tested WSL1, GitBash, CMD and powershell. The shell returns immediately, but if you do a `docker ps` you'll find the container still running...

I learned, that using

```
docker run --init -it alpine sleep 120
```

almost solves this problem for me. Unfortunately i need to redirect output, which conflicts with usage of `-t` (Surprisingly only on Windows. On Linux, docker is happy with that too, but this time really needs the --init, otherwise it would block ctrl-c)

```
docker run --init -it alpine sleep 120 > somefile.log
```

Even in GitBash, usage of winpty does not work.

EDIT: I just realized, that the last command also seems to work for CMD and PowerShell. Only WSL and GitBash are misbehaving...

How do i make the container stop using CTRL-C on windows in WSL and GitBash?

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR
Historically you CAN'T.

I doubt this will change anymore, since, after all these years, this is probably no longer considered a bug but a feature :S. It's bound to be in many shell scripts/batch files that would break.

Perhaps run docker in the new Linux subsystem for Windows. Enable the checkbox in Docker for Windows if you use that:
https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/wsl/

Just use an explicit  `docker container stop ...` on Windows.
You can consider this an automatic '--detached' or '-d' as compared to the Linux way, which you see in many online examples/tutorials anyway.